# How to have "Sub" package.json for "inner projects"

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create one "master" project that will contain all of my other projects that I have worked on, something like a portfolio.

Of course all of these projects have different dependencies and different repositories.

I have started working on that "master project", but it just occured to me that I have no idea how to both keep them separated (as repos and packages) and at the same time run them from the same project?

Is there a way to have "sub package.jsons" for each of them, and keep each of them in their separate repositories, be able to run them individually if I want to, and at the same time have them available as components to the master project?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

Edit: And having a child git repo inside a parent git repo will work as well. You will probably need to add child repo folder to your parent repo .gitignore.

Comment: Okay, and if its possible, how do I achieve that, at the very least, what should I be researching?

Comment: I just checked myself, actually you don't need it. Just add child directory/repo to parent directory/repo's .gitignore, and it will just work.

Comment: Okay, and what about the projects and the different package.jsons?

Comment: Won't be a problem either. Since you have the child directory in your parent directory's .gitignore, nothing in child directory will be tracked by parent directory. both directories will contain a package.json, package-lock.json and node_modules folder. https://i.imgur.com/eDiIw25.png https://i.imgur.com/OGeyvPX.png

Comment: Ah, sorry, i misunderstood your question. - im tired - You want to commit the content of your child repo to your parent repo aswell. Then just add childrepo/node_modules to the parent's .gitignore instead of the entire folder!